# evaluate movement trend

Tags: time-series, correlation, trend

I have some timestamped data (four groups) and I am looking to find a way to find which of the three is moving more closely with the purple one? Is Pearson correlation is the best approach, or there is a better way to do this?

I am not checking the dependency, these are four different metrics coming from different sources, one of them, the purple one, is the most trustable source, so I am trying to find which of the remaining, i.e. the other 3, are closer to the purple one, especially in terms of trend. Pearson Corr is not the best metric as it ignores the timestamp.

To be more specific, I am looking at which of those three are more alligned/synched with the purple one. when Purple goes up/down, which of them goes up/down and whether it is in the same magnitude. I can use lag technique but then do what, not sure about the next step.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that you have a Tabular dataframe with timestamp column as index and 4 groups are features/columns in data, you can definitely apply **pearson correlation** to find the linear dependency. But also, try exploring ***SelectKBest*** which performs **correlation + F-Test** to understand the non-linear dependancy per say.

Comment: What do you mean by: "moving more closely with the purple one"? Do you want the difference to be stable or are you generally interested in the amount of stochastic dependence?

Comment: Thanks, have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are only trying to find the dependancy between the 4 groups `(i like to call them features)` in a given dataset.
Even if you have a timestamp column, it should not hamper testing of

> **Correlation technique, as it gives you the linear dependancy between the groups/features.**

Now, just for information purpose, you can also try out exploring [SelectKBest Methodology](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) as it is combination of:

> ***Correlation + F - Test***

which checks the dependency between the features and target followed by estimating the significance of dependancy.
The F-Test in this method helps in identifying wether the feature and target originates from the same distribution or not, and how well does the correlation explains this relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not checking the dependency, these are four different metrics coming from different sources, one of them, the purple one, is the most trustable source, so I am trying to find which of the remaining, i.e. the other 3, are closer to the purple one, especially in terms of trend. Pearson Corr is not the best metric as it ignores the timestamp.

Comment: Well in that case use `pct_change()` pandas method to get the percentage change observed in the series and then measure correlation. Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVV6IVPUlKU